# JavaScript: form selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Contrary to the question title, the code is working; albeit not entirely as intended.

If one checkbox is ticked, its partner with the same value should also be ticked. Alternately, if one of the checkboxes is unticked, its parter should be unticked as well. This works correctly **once**. Repeat checking/unchecking only triggers if both checkboxes are checked or unchecked.

```js
 alert("hi!");

 $(".checkstylin").change(function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

     $(":checkbox[value='" + val + "']").attr("checked", true);
   } else {
     $(":checkbox[value='" + val + "']").attr("checked", false);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="9">
    <td>9.00</td>

    <td style="background-color:#FFCCCC">
      <input class="checkstylin" name="1" title="B106" type="checkbox" value="MOD10110">MOD10110</td>

    <td style="background-color:#">
      <input class="checkstylin" name="9" title="B103" type="checkbox" value="MOD30010">MOD30010</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="10">
    <td>10.00</td>

    <td style="background-color:#FFCCCC">
      <input class="checkstylin" name="1" title="B106" type="checkbox" value="MOD10110">MOD10110</td>

    <td>High</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="11">
    <td>11.00</td>

    <td style="background-color:#">
      <input class="checkstylin" name="10" title="B103" type="checkbox" value="MOD30060">MOD30060</td>

    <td>High</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="12">
    <td>12.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="13">
    <td>13.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="14">
    <td>14.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="15">
    <td>15.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="16">
    <td>16.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="17">
    <td>17.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="18">
    <td>18.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `prop()`

As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

See: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```js
 alert("hi!");

 $(".checkstylin").on('change',function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

     $(":checkbox[value='" + val + "']").prop("checked", true);
   } else {
     $(":checkbox[value='" + val + "']").prop("checked", false);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="9">
    <td>9.00</td>

    <td style="background-color:#FFCCCC">
      <input class="checkstylin" name="1" title="B106" type="checkbox" value="MOD10110">MOD10110</td>

    <td style="background-color:#">
      <input class="checkstylin" name="9" title="B103" type="checkbox" value="MOD30010">MOD30010</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="10">
    <td>10.00</td>

    <td style="background-color:#FFCCCC">
      <input class="checkstylin" name="1" title="B106" type="checkbox" value="MOD10110">MOD10110</td>

    <td>High</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="11">
    <td>11.00</td>

    <td style="background-color:#">
      <input class="checkstylin" name="10" title="B103" type="checkbox" value="MOD30060">MOD30060</td>

    <td>High</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="12">
    <td>12.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="13">
    <td>13.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="14">
    <td>14.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="15">
    <td>15.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="16">
    <td>16.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="17">
    <td>17.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="18">
    <td>18.00</td>

    <td>High</td>

    <td>Low</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but an explanation why would be helpful.